# Order By String which matches property name gives Null Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am having an issue with the below sorting scenario.

```
var model = DbContext
           .Select(s => new ViewModel)
           .OrderBy(paging.Sorting);
```

**paging.Sorting is a string that is coming from the client and is never NULL.**

**If a column has null values the ordering will throw a null ref exception.**

Is there a way to use lamdba expressions?

This is an error i get very often and i am trying to find a solid solution.

Example:

```
var people = DbContext.People
                      .Select(p => new PersonViewModel{
                      Name = p.Name,
                      ManagerId = p.ManagerId,
                      DepartmentId = p.DepartmentId
                      })
                      .OrderBy(paging.Sorting)
```

Sometimes the 
paging.Sorting = "DepartmentId DESC"

OR

paging.Sorting = "ManagerId ASC"

Some People do not have a Manager and the value of the Id is null.
So the sorting throws a null ref exception.

Comment: you can handle this issue by checking paging.Sorting if it is null then pass default sorting key

Comment: Your code contains errors. Please provide us with the necessary information to analyze the problem. For example: What are you really selecting with `new ViewModel`. Without more information it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar  paging.Sorting is never null.

Comment: @RonyPatel  paging.Sorting is never null.

Comment: @Silvermind i provided a concrete example

Comment: Have you tried moving the `OrderBy` between `People` and `Select`?

Comment: Also are the properties `ManagerId` and `DepartmentId` nullable in your `PersonViewModel` class?

Comment: 'ManagerId = p.ManagerId ? null : "" ' should work, in that case you replace the null value with an empty string. if i understood the problem correct

Comment: @Rafalon i provided a simple example my code has a lot of other properties that belong only to the view model and not the original model. So i cannot do what you say.

Comment: @kurdy `ManagerId` is not likely to be a `string` (I'd say maybe an `int`), but anyway your code should be either `ManagerId = p.ManagerId != null ? p.ManagerId : ""` (with ternary operator) or `ManagerId = p.ManagerId ?? ""` (with null coalescing operator)

Comment: @panoskarajohn so you mean you try to use `OrderBy` on a field that is not part of the original model? Isn't this what actually triggers the error?

Comment: @Rafalon please see Musab.BA 's answer

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE] so we can better help with your problem?

Comment: @Rafalon this is the best i can do. You can setup a simple Entiry Framework project with 2  tables and test this yourself. What from the question does not make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by property name without type reflection

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
    {
      public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string 
      propertyName)
      {
      return (IQueryable<T>)OrderBy((IQueryable)source, propertyName);
      }

      public static IQueryable OrderBy(this IQueryable source, string propertyName)
      {
        var x = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
        var body = propertyName.Split('.').Aggregate<string, Expression>(x, 
        Expression.PropertyOrField);

        var selector = Expression.Lambda
         (Expression.PropertyOrField(x, propertyName), x);

         return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new Type[] { 
             source.ElementType, selector.Body.Type },
                 source.Expression, selector
                 ));
      }

      public static IQueryable<T> OrderByDescending<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
      string propertyName)
      {
        return (IQueryable<T>)OrderByDescending((IQueryable)source, propertyName);
      }

      public static IQueryable OrderByDescending(this IQueryable source, string 
      propertyName)
      {
        var x = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "x");
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.PropertyOrField(x, 
        propertyName),x);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
            Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "OrderByDescending", new Type[] { 
             source.ElementType, selector.Body.Type },
                 source.Expression, selector
                 ));
      }
}
```

then you can use it like this

```
var people = DbContext.People
                      .Select(p => new PersonViewModel{
                      Name = p.Name,
                      ManagerId = p.ManagerId,
                      DepartmentId = p.DepartmentId
                      })
                      .OrderBy(paging.Sorting)
```

or you can do it with type reflection (without IQueryableExtensions) (although it is not very efficient):  like this

```
var people = DbContext.People
                          .Select(p => new PersonViewModel{
                          Name = p.Name,
                          ManagerId = p.ManagerId,
                          DepartmentId = p.DepartmentId
                          })
                          .OrderBy(o => o.GetType()
                          .GetProperty(paging.Sorting)
                          .GetValue(o, null))
```

Comment: Well you are in the right track. But the paging.Sorting 
value is "ManagerId ASC" "ManagerId DESC"

Comment: @panoskarajohn you can make client side send ASC Or DESC in different parameter and based on it you can use (OrderBy(),OrderByDescending())

Comment: I know that I can hack my way around this. I did .Split() to make your solution work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate it with following snippet and it works perfectly fine, can you please share more details about the error or the code snippet

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

    List<customobj> items = new List<customobj> {
                new customobj{num=1,text="Ab"},
                new customobj{num=2},
                new customobj{num=3,text="cc"},
                new customobj{num=4,text="dd"},
                new customobj{num=5,text="ee"},
            };
            var item = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy("text DESC");
```

Comment: Well, you used `OrderBy(x => x.text)`. Did you try with `OrderBy("text DESC")` as OP suggests?

Comment: the code you are writing is using Lambdas. 
My code is using the sorting with string.
Also i am querying a database.Please see my example.

Comment: I didn't see the updated code, when i post this answer and will update it and i wasn't able to post it as comments also.. will check it out

Comment: tried with linq dynamic and its working perfectly var item = items.AsQueryable().OrderBy("text DESC");

Comment: @panoskarajohn Have you tried linq.dynamic which doesnt require lambda expression to specify the order by column

Comment: It seems you do not quite get the problem at hand.

Comment: @panoskarajohn well this answer illustrates that `OrderBy` seems to handle `null` items just fine. Therefore your problem *might* come from somewhere else?

Comment: @Rafalon no it does not. It uses a simple list which will not be the case when using DbContext. You want the sorting to happen on the sql server not on the client. 
Musab.BA(above) is on the right track. You need an IQuereyable extension method. His example is not at full operation. I will construct the extension method myself and provide as an aswer. 
The toList() will bring all of the data in memory.  
I brought this to the community for a simple solution or to see how i would be able to construct the extension method. I got the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do an inline check and have a 'default' fallback for the order...in case ManagerId is null.

So, something like:

```
string defaultOrder = "DepartmentId DESC";

var people = DbContext.People
    .Select(p => new PersonViewModel{
        Name = p.Name,
        ManagerId = p.ManagerId,
        DepartmentId = p.DepartmentId
    })
    .OrderBy(p => (paging.Sorting.ToLower().Contains("managerid") && p.ManagerId == null) ? defaultOrder : paging.Sorting)
```

*I've just done this really quickly so forgive any typos*

Comment: I have like a million properties. This is a solution fir a small scale solurion.
Please see Musab.BA 's answer. He is on the right track.

Comment: OK, that's fine. Scale of the problem wasn't implied in your OP.